# Is there a limit to the amount of books to a child?

Tags: young-author

I was just wondering if there was a restriction to the number of books a child can write? Is there?

Comment: Like a legal restriction?

Comment: Why do you think there might be?

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no limit, other than how fast she can type.

To get published, she would need a parent or guardian to sign publishing contracts on her behalf.